# template signature resolving to void(void) rejected by gcc; is this valid C++?

Tags: c++

I think this code is valid C++.  MSVC agrees but gcc seems to disagree.  Are MSVC and I wrong?  (Or should I be typing something slightly different?)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <functional>

template <typename T>
struct S
{
  template <typename R>
  void f(std::function<R(T)> fn)
  {
    auto p = &fn;
    ++p;
  }
  template <typename R>
  void g(std::function<R(void)> fn)
  {
    auto p = &fn;
    ++p;
  }
};

void f()
{
  S<void> s;
  auto p = &s;
  ++p;
}

int main()
{
    f();
}
```

error message:

```
<source>: In instantiation of 'struct S<void>':

<source>:26:11:   required from here

<source>:11:8: error: invalid parameter type 'void'

   void f(std::function<R(T)> fn)

        ^

<source>:11:8: error: in declaration 'void S<T>::f(std::function<R(T)>)'

Compiler returned: 1
```

gcc seems to be fine if I write the literal, `void`, as the parameter type (see parameter to function `g()`).  But it is unhappy if I write `T` and then resolve `T` to `void` (see parameter to function `f()`).

Comment: Template parameter pack would fix this.

Comment: Hmmm... I need to pass a callable that takes a `T` (or nothing, if `T` is `void`).  I'm not experienced enough with parameter packs to know how I could leverage them to accomplish this purpose.  Unless I put in a `static_assert((is_same_v<T,void> && sizeof...(Args)==0) || (sizeof...(Args)==1))`?  I'll think a bit more on it.  Thanks for the nudge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, your example is not valid C++.  The rule that allows `(void)` to be a function parameter list with no parameters is found in [Standard section [dcl.fct], paragraph 4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.fct#4):

> A parameter list consisting of a single unnamed parameter of non-dependent type `void` is equivalent to an empty parameter list. Except for this special case, a parameter shall not have type *cv* `void`.

The key for your question is the word "non-dependent", meaning not depending on a template parameter.  The requirement was probably written this way because it would be too surprising to write the function declaration `void func(T);` within a template, expecting it to always be a function type taking exactly one parameter, and then find in one case it might not be.

So:

```
void f1(void);           // okay - classic style from C

void f2(void nothing);   // error - the phony "void" parameter cannot be named

void f3(const void);     // error - const void is a different type

using VoidType = void;
void f4(VoidType);       // okay - using a non-dependent type alias

template <typename T>
void f5(T);
void (*fptr)(void) = f5<void>; // error - dependent parameter type cannot be void
```

Comment: "non-dependent": even if I *had* known where in the standard to look, that very important modifier would have escaped my notice.  Now I can avoid frustrating attempts to avoid writing a specialization (which is where I was most likely headed).